# Positive Harmonic functions that can be extended to boundary

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a bounded domain with smooth boundary $\partial \Omega$. Let $u \in C^\infty(\Omega)$ be a positive harmonic function. I wonder under which assumption, we can find a $\tilde{u} \in C^\infty(\Omega) \cap C(\partial \Omega)$ harmonic, such that $\tilde{u}=u$ in $\Omega$? Could anyone give me some examples or counterexamples?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works iff $u$ is uniformly continuous.

If $u\colon\Omega\to(0,\infty)$ is uniformly continuous, then it extends to a continuous function on the completion $\tilde{u}\in C(\overline{\Omega};[0,\infty))\subset C(\overline{\Omega})$.

Conversely, since $\Omega$ is bounded, $\overline{\Omega}$ is compact so any continuous $\tilde{u}$ is uniformly continuous, hence $u=\tilde{u}\vert_\Omega$ is too.

Note there isn't really any need to restrict to $u$ positive, or $\partial\Omega$ smooth.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! I think that is what I need!